# Error with arduino: does not name a type

Tags: arduino

I have some problem with my own arduino library. Compiler does not recognize my class **Platform** and says: "**error: 'Platform' does not name a type**".

Here is the main program code:

```
#include <Platform.h>

#define MOVE_FORWARD  0xFF
#define MOVE_BACKWARD 0xF0

// Error 'Platform' does not name a type
Platform plt(13, 14, 15);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.read() == MOVE_FORWARD)
        plt.move(5);
    if (Serial.read() == MOVE_BACKWARD)
        plt.move(-5);
}
```

Here is the Platform.h code:

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_H
    #define PLATFORM_H

#include <arduino.h>
#include <Motor.h>

class Platform {
    public:
        Platform(int input_1, int input_2, int enable); // Pins for L293D
        void move(int distance);
    private:
        Motor *m_motors; // All motors connected to one L293D
};  

#endif
```

And implementation of Platform:

```
#include "Platform.h"

Platform::Platform(int input_1, int input_2, int enable){
    m_motors = new Motor(input_1, input_2, enable);
}

void Platform::move(int distance){
    byte mm_delay = 100;
    byte motor_power = 128;
    if (distance > 0)
        m_motors->forvard(motor_power);
    else if (distance < 0)
        m_motors->backward(motor_power);
    delay(mm_delay*distance);
    m_motors->stop();
}
```

The behavior of the compiler is pretty strange for me because the Motor library work nice and structure of Platform.h is the same as structure of Motor.h.

Answer (score 0):

From above program it is clear that error report your getting because of below reason . you need to change header include file from `#include <Platform.h>` to `include "Platform.h"`.

Comment: You say that I need to replace **#include <Platform.h>** for the **#include "Platform.h"** in the main program, it's right? It not helps me. And this method is suitable for files which placed in the same directory as the file, but Platform library placed with other libraries.

Comment: Then why there is difference of declaration of header file **#include "Platform.h"**  in code tag 3 and **#include <Platform.h>** code tag1

Comment: In code tag 3 placed implementation of Platform class. Both **Platform.h** and **Platform.cpp** placed in one directory **Platform** which    
in its turn placed in the standart arduino's directory for libraries -> Platform is library and it can be attached to the main program by **#include <Platform.h>** declaration as any other library.
You think that code itself is right? Therefore I should to recheck library's installation paths and Arduino IDE settings.